# Ants moving on a grid

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I got asked this as a programming interview question so the "correct" solution is via simulation, but I'm curious about the existence of an analytic solution.

> Two ants start in opposing corners of an 8x8 grid and after each turn, pick a valid direction (N, S, E, W) to move uniformly randomly until they arrive on the same square. What is the expected number of moves?

It seems similar to a number of problems and looks simple enough that I feel there could be an analytic solution, but any approach that I come up with ends up having some flaw that I can't account for.

Comment: Did you get any answer by simulation?

Comment: Yes, the solution via simulation is trivial, but not what I'm interested in.

Comment: Okay, wanted to verify my simulation first before going with the analytic one. I am getting about 200 turns, is it what you get too?

Comment: Ah, I got ~82 turns. I verified this was correct with someone else who wrote the simulation as well. I don't want to share my code since this is an interview question, but someone posted theirs on a similar question here: https://gist.github.com/dhalik/51a5c0dc621a43d3bb94

Comment: Hmm, then it's mistake with my code. Result of that code is close to my analytical answer for a 3x3 board ($\frac{234}{37} \approx 6.324$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually need a lot fewer states due to the symmetry. There are only $\frac{4(4+1)}2=10$ inequivalent squares, and the two ants are always on the same colour of the checkerboard, so there are only $\frac{10\cdot64}2=320$ inequivalent states. Thus, the linear system of equations obtained by first-step analysis, $x=Px+e$ (where $x$ is the vector of expected times to completion, $P$ is the transition matrix and $e$ is a constant vector containing $0$ for terminal states and $1$ for all other states) can be comfortably solved. [Here’s Java code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question1469342.java) that does this.

The result is

$$
\\[10pt]\frac{165717462194240075690785247324342135802521193767596288772233236947815341350849686583909366015331800669954}{2002646571603584097429871888873116696850609094744365242723213379788582943418043779999464474895914902977}
\\\approx82.75\;,
$$

in agreement with the simulations mentioned in the comments. [Here’s Java code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question1469342Simulation.java) for a simulation.

Answer (score 1):

In principle you can do this using a (rather large) Markov chain. You have $64^2$ states of the form $(i,j,k,l)$ indicating that the ants are at $(i,j)$ and $(k,l)$. If $A$ is the transition matrix then I think you'll need to look at $\frac{d}{dt}(I-tA)^{-1}$ at $t=0$.  But $A$ is a $4096\times4096$ (sparse) matrix, so this is a challenge. It would make a great programming problem!

Comment: It should have a simpler solution.. On the second thought, not very likely.

Comment: @zhoraster actually I think it does. The ways for ants to meet at time $t$ correspond to paths of length $2t$ from the lower left corner to the upper right. So you only need to consider $64$ states!  I'll update when I get time.

Comment: But don't forget that these are very special paths, with certain self-avoidance.

Comment: @Tad how would you invert that matrix in a reasonable amount of time? An O(n^3) algorithm would be rather slow. I could see maybe doing it via Cholesky factorization though?

Comment: @Tad: Since you're still around, you might want to take a look at my answer :-)